# Reading an unknown number of values from standard input in C

Tags: c, input

I need to read an input file like this:

```
0.142857 0.714286 
0.642857 0.714286 
0.285714 0.500000
0.500000 0.500000 
0.785714 0.428571 
0.357143 0.357143 
0.714286 0.214286 
0.928571 0.071429
```

Each line corresponds to a point on a plane, with an unknown number of points
input comes from standard input..

any ideas?

Comment: If this is homework please tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust the input enough, use `scanf()`.

Verify the return value to make sure a pair was read, test for EOF and you're all set.

```
double x, y;
while (scanf("%lf%lf", &x, &y) == 2) {
  /* deal with (x, y) */
}
if (!feof(stdin)) /* input error */;
```

**NOT TESTED**

---

If you don't trust the input, use `fgets()` and parse each line "by-hand"

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` returns the number of parameters is receives. You can test to make sure you're getting what you're asking for.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// ...

double f1, f2;

while(scanf("%lf %lf", &f1, &f2) == 2)
{
  // store f1 and f2 somewhere
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read each pair and add it to a Linked List until you get all pairs in the input?